# Trac svn centos issues

Tags: centos, trac

Have setup Trac/SVN following instructions from tutorial at

http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-install-subversion-with-trac-on-centos-5-x/

SVN works fine at

```
/svn/
```

Trac ur:

```
/trac/
```

Trac does not, the error it througs is

```
   Not Found

   The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an   ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Trac.conf file is

```
###
### Sample Trac configuration taken from http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython    
###

### The recommended Trac web interface requires mod_python
<IfModule mod_python.c>

### Create your Trac environments as subdirectories of /var/trac
### They will appear in a listing on your website at /trac/, and be available 
### at /trac/PROJECTNAME/
<Location /trac>
    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
    PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend 
    PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/www/trac
    PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
</Location>

### Use htpasswd to add Trac accounts to the AuthUserFile
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Trac"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/trac/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Apache Error Log

```
[Mon Nov 15 16:07:08 2010] [error] [client 10.10.0.14] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 15 16:07:08 2010] [error] [client 10.10.0.14] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 15 16:07:08 2010] [error] [client 10.10.0.14] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Nov 15 16:07:08 2010] [error] [client 10.10.0.14] script '/var/www/html/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: Do you have mod_python installed?

Comment: Package mod_python-3.2.8-3.1.i386 already installed and latest version

Comment: Post your trac.conf file? Did you look at the Apache error log for more details?

Comment: trac.conf file added above

Comment: and Apache error log?

Comment: apache log file seems to be empty

Comment: Did you set the ErrorLog directive in the httpd.conf, something like this: ErrorLog logs/error_log?

Comment: apache error log added above as well

Comment: Does the index.php file exist in /var/www/html? If so, what is its permission? If not, touch a empty file, chown to apache and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trac isn't written in PHP, so the index.php error is curios. Also, your error log doesn't show trac in the request. It seems to be requesting index.php from the root of your server. What happens if you request http://servername/trac/ ? Your Apache conf shows it being in that location.